# AngularJS: Resolve and lazy loading services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using [this method](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx) for lazy-loading the controllers/services required for each of my AngularJS routes.

Basically, for each route, I define the dependencies (e.g the controllers, services, etc needed), then a function is added to the `resolve` of the route definition for that route, that function dynamically loads the javascript files of the dependencies.

This works, however where I run into a problem is this. Suppose that I wanted to lazy-load a service called `fooService` for the route `/foo`. However, what if I also wanted to have `fooService.getResults()` added to the resolve for `/foo`? This gives an error because perhaps the `fooService.js` file is not loaded by the time the resolve function for `fooService.getResults()` is called.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: can you provide some code or a fiddle for this?

Comment: @Voltage All the code involved is pretty much in the url I gave.